# Created 100GB ec2 instance, but only shows 10GB?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, partition

I just created a new EC2 instance of 100gb with only 1 storage disk.

However, my `df -h` output shows the following :

```
[root@ip-10-252-37-164 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1            5.5G  2.9G  2.3G  56% /
tmpfs                 296M     0  296M   0% /dev/shm
[root@ip-10-252-37-164 ~]#
```

How is this possible ? Where is the rest 90GB of my disk ? 
How do I get the full 100G on /dev/xvde1 ?

`lsblk` gives me this output :

```
[root@ip-10-252-37-164 ~]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvde    202:64   0   100G  0 disk
├─xvde1 202:65   0   5.5G  0 part /
└─xvde2 202:66   0 488.7M  0 part [SWAP]
[root@ip-10-252-37-164 ~]#
```

I tried using resize2fs, but I get this error :

```
[root@ip-10-252-37-164 ~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 1447753 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Comment: It's there - we can see it, you just need to grow your partition and filesystem.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the type of filesystem that /dev/xvde1 is formatted with.

Comment: You're in the wrong place if you have to ask this, remember when you signed up for here - there was all these screens saying the site's for IT professionals and that we have a site (superuser.com) for learners/amateurs.

Comment: I tried using resize2fs but I get an error for that too.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ would also be appropriate for this level of question.

Comment: @WarDoGG Posting "I get an error for that too" is like us posting "We know how to fix this for you" and leaving it at that.

Comment: After resizing the volume, `resize2fs` will work for `ext4` and `xfs_growfs` for `xfs`. [source](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=430338)

Answer (score 2):

The space exists on the disk, you just need to make it available. The simplest thing to do here is to

- Use [fdisk](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-fdisk/) to create a new partition
- Create a filesystem using [mkfs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs)
- Add the new partition into a convenient filesystem location using [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).
- Update the /etc/[fstab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I corrected my EC2 instance to give me the full amount of disk space.  Yours might be slightly different since you have a swap file.

[How to maximize AWS Default Partition Size? (NOT a duplicate)](https://serverfault.com/questions/672607/how-to-maximize-aws-default-partition-size-not-a-duplicate?lq=1)

Comment: Down votes, really?  The provided link is the only response which provides an answer to his/her question: "How do I get the full 100G on /dev/xvde1?"